# Rydberg and electrical energy

Tags: energy, hydrogen, electrochemistry

I am a high school student. This year I learned the Rydberg constant and its use of finding energy of an electron in chemistry, besides in physics I learned to calculate the energies of two loaded objects. So, I used $$k\times \frac{ q1\times q2}{d}$$
where 
$k$ is $9 \times 10^9$, $q1$ is charge of an electron = -q2, $R$ is $-2.18 \times 10^{-18}$, and $d$ is distance of first orbital (radius of hydrogen)

and carried it on to the first one, which is equal to the energy of a hydrogen's electron. The thing is, my physics equation is equal to 2 Rydbergs. I would be most grateful, if someone explained me what wrong is.

Comment: This site supports [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations and mathematical expressions; your question will get more attention if it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should note that the calculation of the energy in the hydrogen atom is based on the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) and this gives a highly misleading idea of what the atom is like. The electron in a hydrogen atom doesn't orbit the proton like the Earth orbits the Sun. In fact the ground state of hydrogen has zero orbital abgular momentum so the electron doesn't orbit at all. The Bohr model was superceded by quantum mechanics, and QM gives a very different description of the hydrogen atom.

But as long as you bear in mind that your calculation is just for fun and isn't a valid description of the physics, we can answer your question very easily. Your equation:

$$ V = \frac{kq_1q_2}{r} $$

calculates the potential energy. Note that this energy is negative because the charges of the electron and proton have different signs so the energy is $V = -2R$ as you say. To get the total energy you have add the kinetic energy of the orbiting electron and the kinetic energy is $T = +R$. The total energy is:

$$ E = T + V = R + -2R = -R $$

And that's why the total energy is $-R$.

Incidentally, you might have spotted that the kinetic energy is half the (negative of the) potential energy:

$$ 2T = -V $$

This isn't a coincidence! This relationship is due to the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem). It applies to all inverse square law forces, so it applies to gravity as well. For example it tells us that the Earth's kinetic energy is half its gravitational potential energy.